# I need to understand, how the P in the $bP$ is equal to $K(1-(b/a)$ in the following

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

From An Invitation to Biomathematics:

> To illustrate this concept mathematically, assume that a population grows according to the logist model $\frac{dp}{dt}=a(1-\frac{P}{K})P$ and that harvesting yield per time unit is proportional to the size of the population. The harvesting will then decrease the rate of change for the population by a factor of $bP$, where $b>0$ represents the harvesting effort. The rate of change of the population size accounting for the harvesting will then be $\frac{dP}{dt}=a(1-\frac{P}{K})P-bP$. The new non zero equilibrium state for this model is $P=K(1-\frac{b}{a})$, which corresponds to the harvesting yield $Y(b)=bP=bK(1-\frac{b}{a})$.

The above passage shows that $P$ in the $bP$ is equal to the $P$ when $\frac{dP}{dt}=0=a(1-\frac{P}{K})P-bP$. So my question is why author has only substituted this equilibrium $P$ value with only in the $bP$ and not in the preceding term $a(1-\frac{P}{K})P$.

Comment: Well... This compares the equilibria of the dynamics $P'=a(1-P/K)P$ and $P'=a(1-P/K)P-bP$ (and not $P'=a(1-P/K)-bP$, there is a typo in the question). These are obtained by setting to zero the RHS of these differential equations, thus, these equilibria $P^*$ solve $a(1-P^*/K)P^*=0$ and $a(1-P^*/K)P^*-bP^*=0$ respectively. Looking at $P^*\ne0$ one gets $P^*=K$ and $P^*=K(1-b/a)$ respectively. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Ok... So, what you are saying here is that at equilibrium state (without harvesting) the $P$ will be equal to carrying capacity $K$. But as we are harvesting now, so a shift of equilibrium will occur and new equilibrium will be determined by $P*=K(1-\frac{b}{a})$. Am I right on this? I think I am understanding your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the right hand side to be zero gives us (you forgot a $P$ in your equation)
$$a(1-\frac{P}{K})P-bP=0$$
Since we are seeking nonzero equilibrium point, we can divide both sides by $P$. This yields
$$a(1-\frac{P}{K})-b=0\\ \implies 1-\frac{P}{K}=\frac{b}{a}\\ \implies P=K(1-\frac{b}{a})$$

The author then just want to find the harvesting yield rate at this equilibrium state, so he plugged this $P$ into $bP$, which is the term corresponding to harvesting:

$Y(b)=bK(1-\frac{b}{a})$